# How to configure grails/spring authentication scheme per url?

Tags: spring, authentication, rest, grails

How can I configure a grails application using Spring security such that one set of url's will redirect unauthenticated users to a custom login form with an http response code of 200, whereas another set of url's are implementing restful web services and must return a 401/not authorized response for unauthenticated clients so the client application can resend the request with a username and password in response to the 401.

My current configuration can handle the first case with the custom login form. However, I need to configure the other type of authentication for the restful interface url's while preserving the current behavior for the human interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If I understood right what you want to do, I got the same problem, before! but it is easy to solve it using [Spring Security grails Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)! So, first of all, you have to set your application to use basic authentication:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
```

So your restful services will try to login, and if it doesnt work it goes to 401!
This is easy but you also need to use a custom form to login right?! So you can just config some URL to gets into your normal login strategy like this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter'
 ]
```

So noticed, that above, everything that comes to the URL /api/ will use the Basic Auth, but anything that is not from /api/ uses the normal authentication login form!

**EDIT**

More information goes to http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/16%20Filters.html

Comment: Also, be careful not to get bitten by this bug, lest you waste hours trying to figure out why this doesn't work for you: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-210

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and did not found a good solution for this. I am really looking forward a clean solution (something in the context like multi-tenant).

I ended up manually verifying the status and login-part for the second system, which should not redirect to the login page (so I am not using the "Secured" annotation). I did this using `springSecurityService.reauthenticate()` (for manually logging in), `springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()` and manually in each controller for the second system. If he wasn't, I have been redirecting to the specific page.

I do not know, whether this work-around is affordable for your second system.

Answer (score 0):

You should make stateless basic authentication. For that please make following changes in your code.
**UrlMappings.groovy**

```
"/api/restLogin"(controller: 'api', action: 'restLogin', parseRequest: true)
```

**Config.groovy**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.basic.realmName = "Login to My Site"
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
                '*'         : 'statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,customBasicAuthenticationFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,anonymousAuthenticationFilter,basicExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor',
                '/api/': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter'
        ]
```

**resources.groovy**

```
statelessSecurityContextRepository(NullSecurityContextRepository) {}

    statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, ref('statelessSecurityContextRepository')) {
    }
    customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint(CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        realmName = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.basic.realmName 
    }

    customBasicAuthenticationFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter, ref('authenticationManager'), ref('customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint')) {
        authenticationDetailsSource = ref('authenticationDetailsSource')
        rememberMeServices = ref('rememberMeServices')
        credentialsCharset = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.basic.credentialsCharset // 'UTF-8'
    }

    basicAccessDeniedHandler(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl)

    basicRequestCache(NullRequestCache)

    basicExceptionTranslationFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter, ref('customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint'), ref('basicRequestCache')) {
        accessDeniedHandler = ref('basicAccessDeniedHandler')
        authenticationTrustResolver = ref('authenticationTrustResolver')
        throwableAnalyzer = ref('throwableAnalyzer')
    }
```

**CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.groovy**

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends
        BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {   

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {            
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

}
```

**ApiController**

```
@Secured('permitAll')
class ApiController {
def springSecurityService
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
    def restLogin() {        
        User currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
        println(currentUser.username)
     }
}
```